# Passing the Lv.1 Judge Exam

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have Lv.1 Judge exam test 2 month later and I'm start to prepare now

I found I have to read and study Comprehensive Rules, IPG, MTR.

and I will try some test question on Judge center too

I found it's too much to read..should I read all those document carefully?

What else should I check? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not a judge, but it seems advisable to read and study the Comprehensive Rules, so that you can understand them and remember them well enough to apply them in games.

Comment: Relevant thread. http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/magic-fundamentals/magic-rulings/251939-how-to-become-a-magic-judge

Comment: Please remember, all content on the test is confidential. You may discuss it with your L2, but not with anyone else (especially not online!)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad. "Do you have any tips or advice or links?" is not a practical question with a single best solution for a Stack Exchange site to answer, it's an invitation to a discussion. You should discuss this on an MTG forum.

Comment: This is a common question and there is a reasonably narrow set of things that are recommended by Judges, it will have a single set of instructions that the vast majority of judges would agree with. It is also a question that Google should provide lots of good answers to, so closing it wont hurt too much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is important to study effectively for the L1 exam. Remember that the L1 exam is just the first step into the judge program and isn't intended to be too gruelling.

The IPG isn't part of the L1 test at all. The L1 test only uses the JAR (Judging at Regualar REL) for it's questions where the players have done something wrong.

When studying the CR (Comprehensive Rules) focus on just the following topics:

- Parts of the turn and the things that happen in each of them
- How spells and abilities are played
- How they resolve
- How the layers interact
- What Two-Headed Giant is (really just read the 2HG FAQ).

A couple of quick skims of the MTR are likely to be enough for the few questions that might be based on it. There will be a few things in there that might surprise you, those are the bits to remember.

Most usefully log onto the Judge Center (judge.wizards.com) and do some practice tests. Easy Practice tests are a good gauge of how hard the L1 test is and the fully explained answers will help you understand what you didn't understand.

The other thing that must be done is you need to judge a few events, preferably with the Level 2 judge that will be testing you. Judging a couple of events is required before you can be certified as a Level 1 judge. Remember you don't need to be certified to judge events.

Comment: Here is a link to the page on the Magic Judges website that covers what this answer says: https://blogs.magicjudges.org/o/judge-testing/the-level-1-exam/

Answer (score 6):

Yes you should read them thoroughly because as a judge it is your duty and responsibility to understand all of those documents thoroughly so that you can issue rulings to players and be able to explain to them them why a ruling is being made. You would be doing a disservice to everyone involved if you issued bad rulings in a tournament do to a lack of understanding of the rules and documents.

Comment: Surely there are corners of the rules that most L1 judges don't have memorized right away though - I can't imagine you need to read them all thoroughly and remember every detail?

Comment: @Jefromi I didn't say memorize in my answer, I said thoroughly understand them and there is an important difference. If you have a good understanding of the documents and rules then it will be much easier to find answers for questions that you don't have the answer to right away. It will also help give a better understanding of the spirit of the rules and make a ruling in cases that may not be explicitly spelled out in the rules. It is never about blatant memorization of the rules as it is easy to misremember something but rather understanding so you can look up and prove when needed.

Comment: I think that's a helpful thing to mention in your answer. The OP might be feeling a little overwhelmed by the idea that they need to read them to study, which suggests they're expecting to be tested on any arbitrary part, and puts on some pressure to memorize.

Comment: @Jefromi The problem is though with exams it is about memorization while when it comes to using the knowledge it is about understanding.

Comment: @JoeW The exams aren't actually that much about memorization for L1 exams. L2 and on moreso, as it is generally more policy based questions comparatively, but you can't get through the L1 exam just with memorization alone.

Comment: L1 judges just need to get most of the things that are going to come up at the average FNM or Prerelease right. Being confidant at judging GPTs and other more important events is part of the progression towards L2. 
The level of rules knowledge this answer is advocating implies an L3 level of rules knowledge. Many L3 judges don't event have that. Judges aren't expected to be perfect.